# Is a UIButton a NSObject

Tags: cocoa-touch, inheritance, uibutton

I have been watching a tutorial on how to make a game for ideas. It has come to my attention that I was not aware if the UIButton or Collection View was a NSObject. The code describes a NSArray and I wanted to know how it would work with a CollectionView and UIButton for my Game.

Comment: Did you look at the UIButton class reference? The answer to your question is in the first line under the title.

Comment: @user2671083 Tell me what is base class is ?And what is it for Objective C

Answer (score 5):

UIControl : UIView : UIResponder : NSObject

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 1):

All objects in UIKit as well as the NS-classes, and other framework classes inherit from NSObject. There may be some edge case I'm not aware of, but any class you create should also inherit from NSObject because that's where all the class init and lowlevel stuff is implemented.

Comment: There are *two* (public) "base classes": NSObject and NSProxy. - Some of the "low level stuff" is defined in the NSObject *protocol*, and both NSObject and NSProxy conform to that protocol.

Answer (score 0):

yes almost every object in objective-c is eventually a child of NSObject. Or in other words NSObject is the parent of almost every Object in Objective-C